# Android App crashing when trying to parse XML

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse a BBC news feed with `PullParser` but it is crashing for some due to a `NullPointerExeception` and I cannot figure out why.

There is also two title tags before the actual first title tag that I want to parse and one description tag before the one I one to parse and I am not totally sure I am handling that correctly but even if I am not, I don't think that is causing the issue, but I could be wrong.

Thanks to anyone taking a look at this!

EDIT:  I should have been using `nextText()` rather than `getText()`

Below is the `PullParser` code

```
 static public class NewsItemPullParser{

    static ArrayList<NewsItems> parseNewsItems(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
        XmlPullParser parser = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(in, "UTF-8");
        NewsItems newsItem = null;
        ArrayList<NewsItems> newsList = new ArrayList<NewsItems>();
        int event = parser.getEventType();

        while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

            switch(event){
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                if(parser.getName().equals("title")){
                    if(!parser.getText().trim().contains("BBC News -")){
                        newsItem = new NewsItems();
                        newsItem.setTitle(parser.getText().trim());
                        Log.d("Title", parser.getText().trim());
                    }
                }else if(parser.getName().equals("description")){
                    if(!parser.getText().trim().contains("The latest stories")){
                        newsItem.setDescritpion(parser.getText().trim());
                        Log.d("description", parser.getText().trim());
                    }
                }else if(parser.getName().equals("pubDate")){
                    newsItem.setPubDate(parser.getText().trim());
                }else if(parser.getName().equals("media:thumbnail")){
                    if(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "width").equals("66")){
                        newsItem.setThmnSmall(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url").trim());
                        Log.d("small thumbnail", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url").trim());
                    }   
                }else if(parser.getName().equals("media:thumbnail")){
                    if(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "width").equals("144")){
                        newsItem.setThmnLarge(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url").trim());
                        Log.d("large thumbnail", parser.getAttributeValue(null, "url").trim());
                    }       
                }

                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if(parser.getName().equals("title")){
                    newsList.add(newsItem);
                    newsItem = null;
                }

            default:
                break;
            }
            event = parser.next();

        }
        return newsList;
    }
```

Here is the `AsyncTask` code:

```
 public class GetNewsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  ArrayList<NewsItems>> {
NewsActivity activity;

public GetNewsAsyncTask(NewsActivity activity){
    this.activity = activity;

}

@Override
protected ArrayList<NewsItems> doInBackground(String... params) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.connect();
        int statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if(statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            return NewsUtil.NewsItemPullParser.parseNewsItems(in);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    //NewsActivity.pd.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<NewsItems> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //NewsActivity.pd.dismiss();
}



 }
```

Here is the log error:

```
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): at     android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at com.example.bbcnewsapp.NewsUtil$NewsItemPullParser.parseNewsItems(NewsUtil.java:34)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at com.example.bbcnewsapp.GetNewsAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetNewsAsyncTask.java:34)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at com.example.bbcnewsapp.GetNewsAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetNewsAsyncTask.java:1)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
 09-27 03:36:25.594: E/AndroidRuntime(1720):    ... 4 more
 09-27 03:36:27.726: I/Process(1720): Sending signal. PID: 1720 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where is line 34 of `NewsUtil.java`?

Comment: `return NewsUtil.NewsItemPullParser.parseNewsItems(in);` in the `AsyncTask` code.  I think it's crashing because it's returning an empty list because something is going wrong with the parsing.  Even if I try to log the very first `parser.getText()`, I get nothing.

Comment: That looks line line 34 from `GetNewsAsyncTask.java`. But the error occurs on line 34 of `NewsUtil.java` **inside** the call to `parseNewsItems()`. Which line is this?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry.  That is the first `parser.getText()` in the first `if` statement.  `if(!parser.getText().trim().contains("BBC News -"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!parser.getText().trim().contains("BBC News -"))
```

This has at least three potential causes for a `NullPointerException`:

1. `parser` is `null`.
2. `getText()` returns `null`
3. `trim()` returns `null`

You initialize `parser` with `XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser()`, which probably is guaranteed to return a non-null reference. Assuming that `getText()` returns a `String`, 3 is impossible. That leaves the first two. This leaves 2 as the most reasonable suspect.

Note that you should still check 1 and 3, just to be safe. You can do this by breaking the `if` condition into separate statements in order to check each return value.

Once you find where the `null` value is coming from, you will need to figure out why it is `null` when you expect otherwise.

**Addendum:**

From the documentation for `XmlPullParser`:

> The method next() advances the parser to the next event. The int value returned from next determines the current parser state and is identical to the value returned from following calls to getEventType ().
>
> Th[e] following event types are seen by next()
>
> START_TAG
>   An XML start tag was read.
>
> TEXT
>   Text content was read; the text content can be retrieved using the getText() method. (when in validating mode next() will not report ignorable whitespace, use nextToken() instead)
>
> END_TAG
>   An end tag was read
>
> END_DOCUMENT
>   No more events are available

So it seems that you need to call `next()` again before you can call `getText()` to get the text inside the tag.

Comment: After testing, it's the `getText()` that's null.  When I also tested `getName()`, I got the correct tag that I was looking for which is `<title>`  The XML tag is looks like:  `<title>BBC News - Home</title>` so `getText()` should be the proper way to grab that text right?

Comment: WAIT!!!  I looked at the documentation again and it is not `getText()`.  It should be `nextText()`  Now that is quite frustrating.